# PhoneGap / Onsen UI - Can't Capture Android Back Button

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I've tried many solutions, but I can't seem to capture the Android 'backbutton' event. All I want to do is prevent the back button from closing the app.

For context, I'm building an HTML5, cross-platform application with the Onsen UI library (which uses AngularJS at the core). I'm using PhoneGap Build to create iOS and Android builds. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Here's my current attempt (that's not working):

```js
module.run(function($rootScope){
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 }, false);
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to treat the event e like you are, I use something like this that works:

```
    onBackButton: function() {
        console.log('User pressed back button.');

        if (<logic to determine if app is at its home screen>) {
            // Go to launcher
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        } else {
            // Logic to determine what view is the "back" view
        }
    }
```

Also are you registering your "backbutton" event listener AFTER the "deviceready" event has been received.  I register mine in the "deviceready" callback function:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    document.addEventListener('pause', app.onDevicePause, false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', app.onDeviceResume, false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', app.onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener('online', app.onOnline, false);

    if (device.platform === 'Android') {
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', app.onBackButton, false);
        document.addEventListener('menubutton', app.onMenuButton, false);
        document.addEventListener('searchbutton', app.onSearchButton, false);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Simon. I have tried similar approaches in recent days, but not that exact syntax so I'll give it another shot in a bit.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, but I couldn't get this to work either. In fact, 'deviceready' never fired at all. I tried it within .run and .controller. I also tried using ons.ready (which did fire) instead of deviceready, but the back button code still never executed.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me :

HTML :

```
<ons-navigator>
    <ons-page var="mypage">
        ...
    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
ons.ready(function () {
    mypage.setDeviceBackButtonHandler(function () {
    doSomething();
  });
});
```